# How to encrypt a Swap partition after install on a multi-os drive?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

My laptop move a lot, and I want to secure it in case somebody get access to it. One of the step is to secure the swap partition, where all memory can be saved.

How to do this using already included tools (i.e. available through apt)?

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments by @guiverc, another solution would be to create a swapfile on an encrypted partition.

Comment: An easy fix is to just switch to using a *swapfile*, which is located on an encrypted partition.   You didn't provide release details, but swapfiles are now default as its easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I did follow:

1/ Preparation

Get the current `<partition>` to be encrypted:

```
sudo swapon --summary
```

Add packages required:

```
sudo apt install cryptsetup
```

Edit the `/etc/crypttab` (or create it) and put this content in it:

```
# name partition keyfile options
swap /dev/<partition> none luks
```

2/ Let's go:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/<partition>
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/<partition>
sudo cryptdisks_start swap
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/swap
sudo swapon --all
```

Modify the `/etc/fstab` to remove the old swap and add the encrypted one:

```
# /dev/<partition or whatever> none swap sw 0 0
/dev/mapper/swap none swap
```

3/ Automate

IF YOUR ROOT PARTITION IS ALREADY SECURED, you can then auto-mount your swap using a key file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/restricted
sudo chmod 0700 /etc/restricted
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/restricted/luks.key bs=4096 count=1
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/<partition> /etc/restricted/swap.key
```

In your `/etc/crypttab`, you can then use the key:

```
swap /dev/<partition> /etc/restricted/swap.key luks
```

Please protect your keyfile, or all this would have been unecessary...